# Redundant parameters, interpretation of Estimates of fixed effects in SPSS

Tags: mixed-model, spss, redundancy-analysis

I am running linear mixed models analyses for the second time. My categorical variable **random1** for group is a dummy variable (1-0), and the output has this error:

- b Parameter is set to zero because it is redundant.

[image: Table of Estimates of Fixed Effects]

[image: Syntax]

How can I interpret my results?

Do I need to fix my data/coding to get reliable results?

Why do I encounter this problem? I have run similar analyses before with the same dependent variable and fixed factors including my dummy variable (but other covariates), this is the first time I have encountered this problem.

I have tried running the analysis without an intercept, it does not work (I still get the error).

I have read a lot about the dummy trap, but struggle to solve my problem. Everything seem incomprehensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error

SPSS will always take one of the dummy variables as the starting point, this is always the highest number of your dummy variable.
In this case the staring point is Random1 = 1.

Here the beta for random1 = 0 is the change in BDI when compared to random1=1, when controlled for all the other variables and interactions.

In same accounts for the interactions with a dummy variable.

You can recode variables if you would like to compare the other way around or if you would have three groups.

I also suggest not adding to many interactions if your data set is not that big.

The str error is almost as big as your beta. Inidacting it might be underpowerd.

Comment: Thank you so much for the useful answer. It really makes sense to me. In my hunt for answers to this issue I've read so many different things online. Do you happen to know where I can find reliable information about this interpretation, i.e. a book or text from a reliable source online?

Comment: @Marie: if you found this answer helpful, then please consider 
[upvoting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) 
and/or 
[accepting](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) 
it.